# BFS can only search shortest path

Tags: algorithm

My question is motivated from a leetcode:

https://leetcode.com/problems/shortest-path-in-binary-matrix/

> Given an n x n binary matrix grid with 1/0, return the shortest path that is a path from the top-left cell (i.e., (0, 0)) to the bottom-right cell (i.e., (n - 1, n - 1)) such that: All the visited cells of the path are 0. All the adjacent cells of the path are 8-directionally connected (i.e., they are different and they share an edge or a corner).

Obviously we will use `queue` for `BFS`:

```
int shortestPathBinaryMatrix(vector<vector<int>>& grid) {
    if (grid[0][0] == 1) return -1;
    int res = 0, n = grid.size(), m = grid[0].size();
    vector<vector<int>> visited(n, vector<int>(m, 0));
    visited[0][0] = 1;
    queue<vector<int>> q;
    q.push({ 0, 0 });
    vector<vector<int>> dirs{ {-1, 0}, {-1, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, -1}, {0, -1}, {-1, -1} };
    while (!q.empty()) {
        ++res;
        for (int i = q.size(); i > 0; --i) {
            auto t = q.front(); q.pop();
            if (t[0] == n - 1 && t[1] == n - 1) return res;
            for (auto dir : dirs) {
                int x = t[0] + dir[0], y = t[1] + dir[1];
                if (x < 0 || x >= n || y < 0 || y >= m || grid[x][y] == 1 || visited[x][y]) continue;
                visited[x][y] = 1; 
                q.push({ x, y });
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

My question is can BFS only solve the shortest path? For example to find all the available paths, then above BFS will not work since here we mark all the visited cells to avoid duplicate visits, which guarantees the result is shortest path. And usually we use recursion to find all available paths.

Here is using BFS to search all paths:

**Update:**

```
vector<vector<vector<int>>> fun2(vector<vector<int>> grid, int x, int y)
{
    vector<vector<vector<int>>> res;
    if (grid[x][y] == 1) return res;
    int n = grid.size(), m = grid[0].size();
    queue<vector<vector<int>>> q;
    q.push({ { x, y } });
    vector<vector<int>> dirs{ {-1, 0}, {-1, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, -1}, {0, -1}, {-1, -1} };
    while (!q.empty()) {
        for (int i = q.size(); i > 0; --i) {
            auto t = q.front(); q.pop();
            unordered_set<string> st;
            for (auto &it : t) st.insert(to_string(it[0]) + ',' + to_string(it[1]));
            int xx = t.back()[0], yy = t.back()[1];
            if (grid[xx][yy] == 2) res.push_back(t);
            for (auto dir : dirs) {
                int x = xx + dir[0], y = yy + dir[1];
                if (x < 0 || x >= n || y < 0 || y >= m || grid[x][y] == 1 || st.count(to_string(x) + ',' + to_string(y))) continue;
                auto tem = t;
                tem.push_back({ x, y });
                q.push(tem);
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BFS *could* be used also to find *all* paths, but then it should not have a `visited` structure that is shared by all paths, but a separate structure for *each* path.

So instead of putting a single cell's coordinate on the queue, you'd put a path on the queue (consisting of coordinates of the cells on the path), and extend those paths with a next node when that node did not yet occur in *that* path.

As you can see that will require a lot more memory than DFS would need, without any clear compensating benefit.

Comment: if you don't use `visited`, how do you avoid the duplicate visit? and if we use `visited` we may miss the paths like A->B, A->C->B (B is marked) e.t.c. Actually could you give some simple code?

Comment: You avoid *cycles*. That's all.

Comment: Pls see my update. I use `unordered_set<string> st; for (auto &it : t) st.insert(to_string(it[0]) + ',' + to_string(it[1]));` I naively build a set of nodes for each path to check if (x,y) is in the path. Is it what you propose? By the way, seems `pair<int,int>` cannot be the key of set.

Comment: Those are language specific considerations. Whatever the language you use, you'd make sure to maintain the identifiers that uniquely identify a cell (this can indeed be a hashset of strings, but better: a hashset of unique integers, like `x*m+y`, and that set could be in practice be an array of booleans). But the whole point in the end is: this is never better than a DFS solution, which uses less memory.